# Could not find method google() for arguments [] on repository container. (flutter)

Tags: android, ios, gradle, flutter

cmd > flutter run

> Launching lib\main.dart on Lenovo A6020a40 in debug mode...
>   Initializing gradle...                                              1.8s
>   Resolving dependencies...
>   * Error running Gradle:
>   ProcessException: Process "C:\Users\Mantu Kumbhakar\Downloads\sytody-master\android\gradlew.bat" exited abnormally:
>   NDK is missing a "platforms" directory.
>   If you are using NDK, verify the ndk.dir is set to a valid NDK directory.  It is currently set to C:\Users\Mantu
>   Kumbhakar\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ndk-bundle.
>   If you are not using NDK, unset the NDK variable from ANDROID_NDK_HOME or local.properties to remove this warning.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 3.065 secs

Failed to notify ProjectEvaluationListener.afterEvaluate(), but primary configuration failure takes precedence.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 27
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating script.

  > Could not find method google() for arguments [] on repository container.
  >                                                                                                                       * Try:
  >   Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.            Command: C:\Users\Mantu Kumbhakar\Downloads\sytody-master\android\gradlew.bat app:properties

Answer (score 0):

This error is sometimes generated when you try to run a project created using an older version of Flutter than the one you're currently using.

The issue can also be found on the [Flutter GitHub repository](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/25127).

Until an official solution to this issue is provided, you can fix it by recreating the project with your newer version of Flutter, as suggested in the above GitHub issue too.

Answer (score 0):

Above, when Abhijeet said: "This error is sometimes generated **when you try to run a project created using an older version of Flutter** than the one you're currently using." is correct.

Causes
When a project is created with flutter create foo several files in the ios/ and android/ sub-directories are created.

Newer Flutter versions might generate these files a bit differently and projects created with older Flutter versions might cause issues.

to fix:

Supposing that your project is in c:\root_of_your_project\name_of_your_project

Delete the ios/ and android/ directories and go to root directory of your project with CMD, and:

c:\root_of_your_project\flutter create -a kotlin name_of_your_project

and

c:\root_of_your_project\flutter create -i swift name_of_your_project